# Conditionally Allow Editing in FormView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, formview

What would be the best way to go about programatically enabling or disabling the ability to edit a FormView in C#? Ideally I'm looking for something like:

```
if (user.IsAdmin())
    FormView.Editable = true;

else
    FormView.Editable = false;
```

But I can't seem to find a property that would let me do that. I have an Edit Item template defined, and so the "Edit" button always comes up when I see the FormView.

If you need any other information, please let me know. I intentionally didn't post any code to keep this as general as possible - I can tailor it to my own situation. Thank you!

Comment: Are you referring to [`FormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.changemode.aspx), or a global allow/disallow flag that can be applied (so if they try to change to edit it won't allow it based on the user's permissions)?

Comment: I'm looking for a global flag. Using FormView.ChangeMode() I can change the mode to whatever I want, but I can't restrict it to only that mode (unless I can and I just don't know how!) Essentially, if I put FormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly) in Page_Load, the FormView will come up in Read Only mode, but there will still be an edit button there that will switch it to Edit mode. I'd like to conditionally disable that button, so that certain people see it and others don't.

Comment: What about modifying the `<ItemTemplate>` so enable/disable the `<asp:button runat="server" id="edit_button" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />`?

Comment: Can I do that via page.cs? It looks like it's not as simple as `FormView1.EditItemTemplate = "<asp...";` , which gives me the error that "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate'". System.Web.UI.ITemplate doesn't seem to have a constructor or any methods that would allow me to edit its contents.

Comment: This would be done in your page markup. `<asp:FormView ...><ItemTemplate><asp:button ...></ItemTemplate</asp:FormView>`

Comment: But if it's in the markup, how would I do it conditionally? In Page_Load I have code to check if a user is an administrator, and then I'd like to enable/disable the button based on whether or not they are

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much for all your help. This appears to be working just fine:

`LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)FormView1.FindControl("EditButton");`
        `btn.Visible = false;`

Comment: `myFormView.FindControl("edit_button").Enabled = false;`

Comment: Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best advice I can give is as follows:

Setup your itemtemplate with the edit button you're looking to target. e.g.

```
<asp:Formview ...>
  ...
  <ItemTemplate>
    ...
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="edit_button" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
    ...
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Then, within your code-behind you can allow/disallow that button based on permissions. e.g.

```
void Page_Load(...)
{
  ...
  ((Button)this.formView.FindControl("edit_button")).Enabled = User.IsAdmin();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! The whole FindControl thing...definitely not what I was expecting to be using, and not what I found through research. Hopefully this helps someone else searching around for how to enable or disable that button!